# Insert text to Tkinter Entry after clearing the widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'd like to have an Entry widget on my app so that when I clear it using the backspace button, it automatically inserts another text like a placeholder...

I have created the below function to create the placeholder stated before, but I'd like to also add that placeholder text right after the user clear the Entry widget.. Is it possible?

```
def placeholder(entry, case: str):
    placeholder = f'type the {case} number...'

    def focusIn():
        if entry.get() == placeholder:
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            entry.config({'foreground': 'Black'})
    def focusOut():
        if entry.get() == '':
            entry.insert(0, placeholder)
            if entry.get() == placeholder:
                entry.config({'foreground': 'Grey'})

    if entry.get() == '':
        entry.insert(0, placeholder)
        if entry.get() == placeholder:
            entry.config({'foreground': 'Grey'})

    entry.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda event: focusIn())
    entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event: focusOut())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you would be better served by using a validate function instead of binding events. Here's a rough outline for you:

```
import tkinter as tk

def placeholder(data, event, widget):
    if event == 'key' and data == '':
        print(f'{widget}: user has cleared all data')
    if event == 'key' and data != '':
        print(f'{widget}: user has typed something')
    if event == 'focusout':
        print(f'{widget}: user has left')
    if event == 'focusin':
        print(f'{widget}: user has joined')
    return True # critical!!

root = tk.Tk()
vcmd = root.register(placeholder), '%P', '%V', '%W'
for i in range(1,5):
    ent = tk.Entry(root, validate="all", validatecommand=vcmd)
    ent.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you explain it please? I can't get it easily...

Comment: Explain how validate works? I don't know how to explain it better than my example. Did you have a specific question?  The docs are here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M13

Comment: I'm reading the docs, but it seems there's no way of getting the widget itself, just its name... I'd like to delete/insert data to the widget passed as parameter to the placeholder function... Would you know how to do that? It's not accepting to use `widget.insert()` or `widget.delete()` because it's not the widget object, but its name.